# Save the output of "Export to Excel" as xlsx and make it portable

Tags: sharepoint-online, export-to-excel

This is my scenario:

I have an SP list that is shared with several members, and I would like to download the data, customize the schema (i.e. add more columns to it), and then share it with the rest of the members. To make it efficient, I have to change the format of "Export to Excel" (i.e. .iqy) to  *.xlsx. This xlsx seems to use that iqy as the connection file and [people](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3736/understanding-sharepoint-exports-to-excel/) say if I move that xlsx to another system (i.e. portable) it will not work. I did an experiment with one of my colleagues (and their laptop) and it seems it is working fine (after clicking on the "refresh data" button in the xlsx file it fetches the data from our SP).

Can somebody please confirm that my understanding is correct and it works fine (converted .xlsx can be a portable file and it contains the connection string and no need to send the.iqy separately and fix the location of the .iqy in the .xlsx)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your excel file contains the connection it self. No need of sending iqy file seperately. Make sure who ever refresh data has accessn to SP.

I tried by deleting iqy. it still refreshes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @mzoners for testing and confirming